# reledmac: Arithmetic Overflow with \Xarrangement[<s>]{paragraph}

Tags: errors, footnotes, paragraphs, reledmac

I started using `\Bendnote` in my document and want to change the these endnotes now to a footnote-apparatus (`\Bfootnote`). This works well, but when I try to arrange it as paragraph using `\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}` I always get an "Arithmetic overflow" error.

Is there a way to get around this error and actually put the footnote-apparatus in a nice shape? Because right now (due to the error) it goes way over the page boundaries.

Comment: Welcome on SE. Without minimal working example, we can't help you. The Xarrangement paragraphe work well in many case. So you must have something which break it, but what?

Comment: I solved the problem already and edited my original post. Thanks for answering anyways!

Comment: In case your solve you own question, you can answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved the problem: the error occured because of a workaround to get an "Office"-linespacing. It looked like this (in case anyone else uses it):

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MSonehalfspacing}{%
    \setstretch{1.44}%  default
    \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.448}%
    \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.399}%
    \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.433}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\MSdoublespacing}{%
    \setstretch {1.92}%  default
    \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.936}%
    \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.866}%
    \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.902}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\MSonehalfspacing
```

I now use the classical `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` which works fine with `\Bfootnote`.